# Inverter with UPS transformer

Tags: transformer, inverter, ups

[Inverter circuit](https://electricalfundablog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Invertor-Circuit.png)

I am trying to replicate the project on this website: https://electricalfundablog.com/make-simple-inverter-home-circuit-step-by-step-method/
 but the recommended transformer is a 9v 0v 9v 5A transformer, can I use this old UPS transformer: ratings on the input side is 7.5v, 0, 7.5v, 17.5v while on the other side(output) it has ratings of 0v, 170v, 195v, 220v, 250v? Do I use the 7.5v 0 7.5v as the input or 17.5v?

Comment: You need a perfectly symmetrical centre-tap at the highest input voltage 17.5 if there is a centre tap or highest L/R ratio for best efficiency

Comment: You would use 7.5 0 and 7.5 because they are symmetrical.

Comment: I was thought so. Thank you!